# references to boundary behaviour d-bar problem solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, several-complex-variables

is there any reference around the subject of boundary behaviour of solutions of $\bar\partial$ problem $\bar\partial u=f$, when $f$ as slow growth at the boundary of a pseudo-convex domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

addendum: even more, I am interested to that kind of result when $\Omega$ is a convex cone.

Comment: Do you have any further regularity assumptions on $f$?

Comment: @AmorFati there is no restriction from this point of view - you can take it $\mathcal{C}^\infty$